# Spring webflow binder not binding collection object

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I'm using spring webflow v2.4.8 in my app, and trying to bind the model properties using `<binder></binder>`. But my collection objects (list1, list2 both ArrayList) never get bound. If I remove the `<binder></binder>` altogether, all properties are getting correctly bound, but in my case that is not an option.

Do I need to use some custom converter here? Any help greatly appreciated

```
 <view-state id="myId" model="myModel" view="myView" >
        <binder>
            <binding property="list1"/>
            <binding property="list2"/>
            <binding property="string1"/>
            <binding property="string2"/>
            .
            .
            .
        </binder>
        .
        .
        .
    </view-state>
```

Comment: what's in `myModel` and myView? can you post some information about those files?

Comment: @rptmat57  myModel is a plain POJO with usual getters and setters, myView is a jsp page. It seems strange that it just works if we didn't give the custom binder though!

Comment: does it work in other places in you code, or is this the first time you are using converter? also, are you extending Spring's CustomDefaultConversionService?

Comment: I'm not using any converters

Comment: does it work if the field is a String instead of a collection?

Comment: @rptmat57 yes, works flawless if the property is a string

Comment: take a look at my answer below. I don't quite remember, but it's possible the converter for collections isn't part of the defaults so you might have to add it manually

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but in my project I have a custom ConversionService, so maybe you can try using one like this:

[EDIT]

Here is an example of a converter using a service (that gets the object from the db)

```
@Named
public class StringToMyType extends StringToObject {

    @Inject
    private MyTypeService service;

    public StringToMyType(MyType myObject) {
        super(myObject);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object toObject(String id, Class<?> targetClass) throws Exception {
        if (id != null && id.length != 0) {
            return service.findById(new Long(id));
        } else return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String toString(Object myObject) throws Exception {
        return Objects.toString(((MyType) myObject).getId());
    }
}
```

and add it here

```
public class CustomDefaultConversionService extends DefaultConversionService {

    @Override
    protected void addDefaultConverters() {
        super.addDefaultConverters();
        addConverter(new MyTypeConverter()
        addConverter(new ObjectToCollection(this));
    }
}
```

it needs to then be registered this way (xml):

```
<webflow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" view-factory-creator="mvcViewFactoryCreator" conversion-service="conversionService"/>

<bean id="conversionService" class="path.to.converter.CustomDefaultConversionService"/>
```

hope this helps

Comment: Tried this.. But no luck

Comment: what objects are in your collection? do you have a custom converter for them if they are not basic types?

Comment: The collections are of custom type, like List<MyType>, and no, there is no custom converter for them

Comment: well that's probably it then. you will need a custom `MyType` converter

Comment: @slashron I edit my answer with an example of converter for `MyType`

Comment: @rptmat57 I have a main model which has multiple custom type fields and in one of the views I should create multiple objects of those type and submit how can I achieve this? can you help with this?

Comment: you should probably use a separate small form for your embedded objects